# multiple strings ws2812 chip led

Tags: ws2811

I want to connect 8 strings of addressable LEDs so the strings do exactly the same thing at the same time.

All 8 strings start at the same point, but radiate outwards.

Would the controller be able to supply strong enough data pulse to drive 8 strings? Is there a maximum??

Comment: Most likely yes (and there is a maximum fan-out), but... what is the controller?

Comment: At this time, this is a design project.  If it won't work, then it won't get built.  If there is one controller which will do this, and not a different one, then I buy the one which will work!  I plan on using the 5m long 150 x 5050 LED strips.

Comment: But do you mean like an Arduino? Some other MCU? Or a RPi? You can add buffers if you really want to be safe.

Comment: My initial thought was to use https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-LED-Strip-RGB-5050-WS2812B-Individually-Addressable-Dream-Color-Backlight-5V/322899691657?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=512024766899&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649 primarily because it is cheap and pre-programmed.

Comment: Then you should probably ask the seller. Even then its unlikely he'll know the information. Since we don't have access to that info unless you can find a datasheet, there is no way we can know for sure either :(

Comment: OK.  As these are Chinese imports, it is - as you said - unlikely the supplier will know.  Worth an ask, and I will probably try it and see. Worst case is that I have to run data 5m back from the outer ends.  I might also mean that the effect of radiating colour change doesn't work if the data is not exactly 150 LED's apart.

Comment: You should look into buffers and line drivers. Put them between the controller and the strips.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should not be a problem with a fanout of 8. There are no pullup or pulldown resistors inherent in the [WS2811 chips](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) (+/-1uA input current), so we need only be concerned with the load capacitance of 15pF x 8 = 120pF maximum, so a 10mA drive will add less than 50ns (10% of the shortest time in the protocol). Something like an Arduino will have more drive current available than that.

Of course you can just send repeated data to a single string rather than fanning out from the center of a star.